# JQuery : find tr(class = x) get td(class =y) count td variables and attribute, than change tr accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

```
<table class="tbl">
<tr>td class= "colorcode" colspan ="5"/><tr>
<tr class="ms.alternative>
<td></td>
<td class="bkcolor"></td>
<td class="bkcolor"></td>
<td class="bkcolor"></td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="5"/></tr>


 <tr>td class= "colorcode" colspan ="5"/><tr>
<tr class="ms.alternative>
<td></td>
<td class="bkcolor"></td>
<td class="bkcolor"></td>
<td class="bkcolor"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="5"/></tr>


<tr>td class= "colorcode" colspan ="5"/><tr>
<tr class="ms.alternative>
<td></td>
<td class="bkcolor"></td>
 <td class="bkcolor"></td>
<td class="bkcolor"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan=""/></tr>

</table>
```

I am new to jquery.. please help me to figure it out.

In the scenario above:

Now my question is: how would you select all `tr` with

```
class ms.alternative than find(td.bkcolor)
get the color of <td.bkcolor>
```

Now, if:

```
 (number of majority of background color of '`tr.ms.alternative`' '`td.bkcolor`' 
 is red)
 {
     change td.colorcode.css(background-color:'red')
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr[class="ms.alternative"]').find('td[class="bkcolor"]').css("background-color");
```

will provide you the backgound color

```
 $('tr[class="ms.alternative"]').find('td[class="bkcolor"]').css("background-color","new color");
```

will change the background-color in your case